# Page not redirecting when given specific url

Tags: php, url, redirect

I'm having this weird problem with page redirecting after an action.
This happends only when I want to redirect to a specifik page.
I get the courrent url like this

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

And send it to my actions file in the actions url like this :

```
lib/actions.php?module=shopping_cart&action=remove_item&removable_id=<?php echo $product_id;?>&current_url=<?php echo $actual_link;?>
```

When recived in the action file i redirect like this :

```
Header("Location:$current_url");
```

It works fine with url's like :

```
http://localhost/restaurant/index.php?module=booking
```

or

```
http://localhost/restaurant/index.php?module=booking
```

But when it comes to this url :

```
http://localhost/restaurant/index.php?module=booking&action=dishes_selection
```

Nothing happends 
Eaven when I try to echo $current_url it shows nothing...
Really frustrating :( 
can someone please help me ??

Comment: Have you tried to echo $_GET['current_url'] ? By default you need to get url parameters from one of the superglobals, see : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of header("location") use redirectTo('link') , javascript redirection using php function like

```
function redirectTo($url)
{
     echo "<script>";
     echo "window.location.href='<?=$url?>'";
     echo "</script>";

}
```